# DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint not picking up the newUri at runtime in Mule 3

Tags: mule

The DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint is not picking up the newUri at runtime in Mule 3. I have pasted my flow and java code snippet below for reference. Initially I add a outbound endpoint to custom router and then through the java code I am trying to update the uri of the outbound endpoint dynamically using the DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint. But the DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint is not getting updated with the newUri at runtime. I have also tried extending AbstractOutboundRouter in place of FilteringOutboundRouter but still the same result. I have seen examples over the net where DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint is working but it is working with Mule2. Can someone please help me to work it out with mule 3. I want to dynamically set the uri using the DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint.

```
<flow name="DemoVipFlow1" doc:name="DemoVipFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" path="rapp"/>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Stage1"/>
<custom-router class="com.vip.DynamicCustomRouter">
<outbound-endpoint address="http://doesnotexist:9999"/>
</custom-router>
</flow>

package com.tivo.vip;

import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.endpoint.EndpointURI;
import org.mule.api.endpoint.OutboundEndpoint;
import org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor;
import org.mule.api.routing.CouldNotRouteOutboundMessageException;
import org.mule.api.routing.RoutePathNotFoundException;
import org.mule.api.routing.RoutingException;
import org.mule.config.i18n.CoreMessages;
import org.mule.endpoint.DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint;
import org.mule.endpoint.MuleEndpointURI;
import org.mule.routing.outbound.FilteringOutboundRouter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class DynamicCustomRouter extends FilteringOutboundRouter {

@Override
public MuleEvent route(MuleEvent event) throws RoutingException {
    MuleMessage message = event.getMessage();
    MuleEvent result;

    if (routes == null || routes.size() == 0) {
        throw new RoutePathNotFoundException(
                CoreMessages.noEndpointsForRouter(), event, null);
    }

    try {
        MessageProcessor ep = routes.get(0);
        EndpointURI newUri;
        if (ep instanceof OutboundEndpoint) {
            newUri = new MuleEndpointURI(
                    "http://${ipAddress}:8899/jolokia/list", muleContext);
            ep = new DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint((OutboundEndpoint) ep,
                    newUri);
        }
        result = sendRequest(event, message, ep, true);
    } catch (MuleException e) {
        throw new CouldNotRouteOutboundMessageException(event,
                routes.get(0), e);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to send to a dynamic URL, your approach is unnecessarily complex. Assuming `ipAddress` is resolvable global property, the following works:

```
<scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        muleContext.client.send('http://${ipAddress}:8899/jolokia/list',
                                eventContext.message)
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

and can be used to replace your `custom-router`.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the response. I could get the above code u have given to work. But could you please clarify my queries: Is there a bug in using DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint in Mule3. While I am using DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint in my JavaComponent I am not able to update the uri dynamically at runtime. The DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint is always sending the requests to its defaultOtuboundendpoint(which was set statically initially). Can you please give me working code of updating the uri dynamically using DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint in Mule3.

Comment: Hi David,I have an http inboundendpoint (set to request-response mode) before the scripting component (which you have given above). In this case the response received from client.send(...) which is a mule message is not directly displayed by the httpinboundendpoint back to caller browser. Do we need to do some processing on the response received from client.send(...) before we send it out to the httpinboundendpoint.

Comment: Property placeholders are resolved at configuration load time not at runtime. So `DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint` can't possibly resolve `${ipAddress}`.

Comment: Is the inbound HTTP endpoint using the `request-response` exchange pattern? If yes, then specify what you mean by "the response is not directly displayed ... to caller browser". One thing you may need to do is copy the relevant inbound properties (HTTP headers, status) received after the script to the outbound scope (using the copy property XML element) so the initial caller gets a valid HTTP response. Without that, it works, but you'll lose some information (headers) from the Jolokia response.

Comment: Hi David,Thanks for your response. Let me rephrase my query regarding DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint. Suppose I have the following code(extracted from the initial query on top):

Comment: Flow code: 
<custom-router class="com.vip.DynamicCustomRouter">    
<outbound-endpoint address="http://doesnotexist:9999"/>   
</custom-router>  

DynamicCustomRouter Java Code:   
MessageProcessor ep = routes.get(0);   
EndpointURI newUri;   
if (ep instanceof OutboundEndpoint) {   
 newUri = new MuleEndpointURI(   
 "http://localhost:8899/jolokia/list", muleContext);   
 ep = new DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint((OutboundEndpoint) ep, newUri);   
}   
result = sendRequest(event, message, ep, true);

Comment: In the above scenario when we do a sendRequest(...) from the java code then the request is being sent to "http://doesnotexist:9999" which was added as an outbound-endpoint in the flow code, but I want the request to be sent to "http://localhost:8899/jolokia/list" (this is the newUri) which I have added to the DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint through the java code. Can you please let me know what is the issue here.

Comment: I shall not be passing ${ipAddress} to DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint. I will be passing a valid ipaddress/url to it which I will be building in java code itself.                                 Issue: DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint is routing to DefaultOutboundEndpoint and not to new MuleEndpointURI in Mule 3.

Comment: I'll need to step debug to find out why the new endpoint URI is ignored (be aware that dynamic endpoints are still very much challenged in Mule: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/commit/8488ed82b448dedde204e7a44786967e8c843469#core/src/main/java/org/mule/endpoint). As a general remark it's better to use higher level constructs (like in the approach I proposed) than trying to deal with the way Mule works internally.

Comment: Thanks David for the response. Could you please share your findings on debugging of DynamicURIOutboundEndpoint.

Comment: Between, I have been following your book 'Mule In Action' to learn Mule. The book is well written and well composed. Thanks :)

Comment: Yay a reader! OK here is the key to the mystery: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/http/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/http/transformers/ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest.java#L177 ie the HTTP endpoint URL is apparently pre-baked into a message property, not used directly. This is most certainly what's missing - hence failing - with your approach. Try adding this property with the desired URL before calling `sendRequest`.